# C# openFileDialog error: file <path> does not exist. Verify that the correct file name was given

Tags: c#, .net, forms, overflow, openfiledialog

I am currently making a sort of file renamer to deal with android not handling long file names very well. I am using `openFileDialog` in `Forms` to select one of the files it should rename. But the dialog displays the message:

> file  does not exist. Verify that the correct file name was given.

I already tried `openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = false;`, but then it just simply returns nothing. It works fine with files that have shorter file names.

Comment: set both `openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = false;` and
`openFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = false;`

Comment: Already tried this. No error, but still returns nothing